# prestashop cart block disappeared

Tags: php, prestashop, cart

I found a problem in my webpage after days since last modified. The block cart disappeared from page. It is available, it is linked to the top, it worked well but now I don't know if maybe other person has modified it or what because it disappeared from day to night.

The web is venuspleasure.com and the cart WAS right in the menu bar. It also disappeared the add to cart button. I looked from solutions online and I tried to put available the user block and the cart (they already were but I refresh them) I now php so you can explain me if you see something in my code. Maybe I delete something, dunno :(

Comment: I would suggest check your configuration maybe someone enabled `Catalog` mode and purchases cannot be made. It is difficult to say, at least what I can see cart or user blocks are not hidden they are not there at all. So this might be your store configuration issue. Also you mentioned that your store was modified, so it might be related to the latest modifications.

Comment: I'll try to do what you said. Yes something were modified in configurations. I changed the theme to custom theme and the error was there too, so seems is not a code problem made by my theme changes ^-^ If I'm not able to fix it maybe I think I have a backup. I'll tell you, thanks! :D

Comment: Thank you very much! :D The problem was the Catalog. Someone activated it. Thanks a lot! :D